# How to query from dblite for scons

Tags: scons

Can i read from dblite? I tried to read the .sconsign.dblite file and understand that it stores the csig information.
I was able to get the csig from

f_rel_src = SCons.Script.File(target_str)

But how do i map this to file it belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some references that may be of some help:

[Programatically reading and writing to the sconsign file](http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-api/SCons.SConsign-module.html)

The [sconsign](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sconsign) linux command.